# Is there a language which allows Inheritance cycles?

Tags: inheritance, programming-languages, cycle

Is there any programming language which allows reflexive inheritance, or inheritance cycles such as this?

If not, is it an impossible thing to allow in any language?

Would there be any use for it other than arbitrary implementation sharing , and participating in heterogeneous arrays?

For example, I can imagine having any field or method added to any of the cycle participant's other base classes or interfaces automatically become available for the entire cycle. Another thought is the representation of equivalence classes.

```
class Thing extends Item, implements A
{

}

class Item extends Concept
{

}

class Concept extends Thing
{

}

Item item = new Thing();
Thing thing = new Item();
A a1 = new Thing();
A a2 = new Item();
A a3 = new Concept();
```

Comment: It's trivial to "allow" any syntactic construct, by giving it arbitrary semantics. The usual semantics of inheritance blow up in your face when you add cycles, it just doesn't fit. Extending it in a meaningful way may be possible, but it's not obvious at all what the result would look like. In short, can you explain what you would want such a thing to **mean**? When some fields and methods are added to `Item`, `Concept`, and `Thing` --- who will inherit what from whom?

Comment: What would be the *point*?

Comment: Possibly having any field or method added to any of the cycle participant's other base classes or interfaces automatically become available for the entire cycle.

Comment: @user889742 How is that any better than adding a member to the topmost class in a normal inheritance hierarchy (except for being much more confusing)?

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of inheritance is to impose some (hierarchical) structure on the participating classes.

Allowing cycles seems to go in the opposite direction, effectively destroying the structure as every item would be related to every other.

It is possible that mutual dependency is what is required, but then that should be expressed explicitly by some other syntactic construct, not by twisting and misusing another one.